# Horizontal blocks using XSL-FO

Tags: xsl-fo

Using XSL-FO, is possible to create horizontal block elements? I want that every line has a variable number of columns with a variable lenght. I don't use table objects because every line has a different number of "columns". Is possible do that using blocks or other elements?

Comment: Possibly. One would normally use fo:float for such things with a known/fixed width for each block. However, you have not presented any code to guess at nor what FO engine you are using (some do not support floats)

Comment: Finally I've used tables. I use Apache FOP and I see that not support floats.

Answer (score 0):

Use multiple `fo:inline-container`. (See https://www.w3.org/TR/xsl11/#fo_inline-container.)

You can set the width of each `fo:inline-container`.  You can fix the height, or you can leave it as `auto`, or you can set it as a length range.  Also, you can set the baseline on which each `fo:inline-container` aligns.

Versions of FOP more recent than your question state that they have limited support for `fo:inline-container`, so this solution might also work with FOP.